# Design a multimedia comment system in mongodb, is it possible to store different structure(both text strucutre and audio structure ) in comments array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create a multi-media comment system, allowing people not only create the comments in text but could be also in audio.

I intend to use mongodb as the database, simply to want to design a simple structure like this implemented in mongodb, in which AudioComment stores the address of the audio, the real audio is stored in GridFS

```
var Content = mongoose.Schema({
    title  :  { type: String }
  , content: { type: String }
  , comments:  [TextComment / AudioComment ]

});
var TextComment = mongoose.Schema({
    name  :  { type: String }
  , date  :  { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  , text  :  String 
  , slug  :  {type:String, index:true}
});
var AudioComment = mongoose.Schema({
    name  :  { type: String }
  , date  :  { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  , audio_ref:  String 
  , slug  :  {type:String, index:true}
})
```

My question is could I design the schema in this way, comments:  [TextComment / AudioComment ], that comments array can accepts both TextComment structure or AudioComment structure ?

My previous experience says it is hard in mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Content = mongoose.Schema({
        title  :  String,
        content: String,
        comments:  {type: this.mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'AudioComment'}
...
```

But i dont know how to switch betwin types in the same field.
And you can use this syntax I find it clearer.